# JUnit Tutorials for a QA Engineer interested in Whitebox Testing

Tags: testing, junit4

I have been trying my hands on opensource tool JUnit for testing Java Code (Read it as from Whitebox testing Perspective), I want to start learning from scratch. Any suggestions on good books , pdf or links to tutorials woulld be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two books and a web site that I found useful:

**Agile Java, Crafting Code with Test-Driven Development**, Jeff Langr, 2005, Prentice-Hall.

[Listing at isbn.nu](http://isbn.nu/9780131482395)

An older book that uses JUnit 3.8.1.

Excellent approach to learn Java, OO design, and TDD.  Good code samples, explanations, and exercises.  See the author's site for more data.  He might also be found on the JavaRanch web site,
javaranch.com,
where more JUnit data can be found.

**Test Driven, Practical TDD and Acceptance TDD for Java Developers**, Lasse Koskela, 2008, Manning.

[Listing at isbn.nu](http://isbn.nu/9781932394856)

See Appx A (Brief JUnit 4 tutorial in 2 pages of annotated code),

and Appx B (Brief JUnit 3.8 tutorial in 2 pages of annotated code)

if you need to translate between the two, eg, if your IDE supports only the older s/w.

I wanted to see both JUnit 3 and 4, and built a VM running Debian's unstable release.  This gave me a more recent version of the Eclipse IDE that supported JUnit 4.